# How to change current working directory using a batch file

Tags: batch-file, directory, command-prompt, drive

I need some help in writing a batch file.
I have a path stored in a variable root as follows:

```
set root=D:\Work\Root
```

Then I am changing my working directory to this root as follows:

```
cd %root%
```

When I execute this batch file from anywhere on the D drive this is done successfully. But when I execute the same batch file from some other drive, cd %root% doesn't work.

Is there a way I can get the drive letter from the root variable? I can then change the current directory to this drive first and then cd %root% shall work.

Answer (score 192, accepted):

Specify `/D` to change the drive also.

```
CD /D %root%
```

Comment: Other answers say `\d` (lowercase) is there a difference between either? Is the option just case-insensitive?

Comment: @josch: Yes, if we are talking about CMD's internal commands, then switch parameters like `/D` above are case-insensitive (`/D` = `/d`), just like the commands themselves (`CD` = `cd`). I believe that is also true for all external Windows command-line utilities (like `FINDSTR`, `SORT` etc.) Third-party tools, on the other hand, can use case-sensitive parameters.

Comment: not worth an own answer, but you can `set "root=/d D:\Work\Root"` and `cd %root%` or even `set "root=cd /d D:\Work\Root"` and just `%root%`

Answer (score 47):

Just use `cd /d %root%` to switch driver letters and change directories.

Alternatively, use `pushd %root%` to switch drive letters when changing directories as well as storing the previous directory on a stack so you can use `popd` to switch back.

Note that `pushd` will also allow you to change directories to a network share. It will actually map a network drive for you, then unmap it when you execute the `popd` for that directory.

Answer (score 38):

Try this

```
chdir /d D:\Work\Root
```

Comment: It should be noted that before and after directory, " should be put like this; chdir /d "D:\Work\Root"

Comment: @AdInfinitum No that's not true, that's only necessary if there's spaces in the path. Just qouting the spaced words works as well, like `C:\"Program Files"\Something\Something`

Answer (score 22):

A simpler syntax might be

pushd %root%

Answer (score 6):

In my batch file I needed to :

1. Change dir to other directory
2. run commands in bat file -- do some work in that directory
3. change back to my original directory

`pushd` solved this with the help of `popd`

**bat file example**

```
pushd <my-working-directory>
do command
do other command
...

popd
```

`popd` moved me back to original directory.