# Change current working directory from batch file and run script

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks, command-prompt

**In Windows 8:** I have a php file which needs to be run from the scheduled tasks through .bat file.
The PHP is located in: **P:\php\php.exe**
The file to run is located in: **W:\folder\file.php**

my .bat file looks like this:

```
cmd /c p:\php\php.exe w:\folder\file.php
```

It does not run. When I open cmd and switch to the file folder and run it from there, the file executes properly.

i.e.: `W:\folder> p:\php\php.exe w:\folder\file.php`

I have to add something to the .bat file which navigates to this w:\folder and executes it in the same manner but I cannot figure out what. I tried other posts (replies) i.e.:
[How to change current working directory using a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138507/how-to-change-current-working-directory-using-a-batch-file)

but it did not take any effect. Can anyone help me to write the correct command for the .bat file please ?

Comment: `"p:\php\php.exe" "w:\folder\file.php"` <--- try that too

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you might try this:

```
start "" /d "w:\folder" /b "p:\php\php.exe" file.php
```

Comment: ..thanks, I will try it the first thing in the morning and let u know.

Comment: Yes! this works. I've tried all kinds of variations an possibilities and this is the only syntax which actually works! Just for completeness, the system is WIN 8.

Answer (score 3):

This may also work:

```
@echo off
cd /d "w:\folder"
"p:\php\php.exe" "file.php"
```

Comment: ..thanks for your reply. I've seen this response in another tread already and I am sure it is correct for all older Win systems. Thank you again. ~m

Comment: Did you try it?  It's a syntax that will work on any Windows NT class system including Windows 8.1

Comment: ..hi, you r right, your syntax is slightly different that the above mentioned post from the other tread. Since I can accept only one answer, I am voting your comment up. Thanks.

Comment: For the sake of curiosity, what does the */d* argument do? And when is it needed?

Comment: @MathiasLykkegaardLorenzen The `cd` command can change the working directory on any drive, and the `/d` switch changes the current drive to match the one you are changing the folder on.    It can be used with every `CD` command - unless you are purposely changing the working directory on another drive without intending to be on that drive.

Answer (score 0):

this is how I solved the problem, try this:

```
cd p:\php\
p:
php.exe w:\folder\file.php
```

this seems to work.