# Launching a monogame game from another program

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I'm trying to run my game built with MonoGame within Tiled Mapeditor through the command line button but my game throw a 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentLoadException'.

The code I use :

```
texture2D = Load<Texture2D>(_file);
```

This also occurs if I run the game in command line from another directory.

The debugging allows me to see that the full path of the content directory is correclty set and doesn't depend of the launching directory as I was suspecting......

[The images shows the correct path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlfiy.png)

The game runs correctly if I run it from the editor or by double clicking the exe file.

I'm quite sure that I'm not the first to try this, so I'm doing something wrong.

Can you help me ?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: You might find better luck over at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/; however, you might be having an issue with the 'start-in' directory and this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18906943/86860