# Windows 8.1 and CD command in Command Line

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1

I run command line of Windows 8.1 as Admin. I'm trying change disk from C:\ to D:.

My command:

[image]

As you can see CD can change only in current (C:) disk. How can I move to D?

I looked for disk D properties and there Admin have all access to all activity:

[image]

Comment: `cd` never changed the current drive unless you also specify the `/d` parameter. run `cd /?` to see details

Comment: The issue is not specific to Windows 8 or Windows 8.1 and has already been raised here: [How to change current working directory using a batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138507/how-to-change-current-working-directory-using-a-batch-file)

Comment: to simply change to the current directory of another drive, type only the drive letter and colon.  Example:  `i:` followed by pressing ENTER will place you in the currently directory of your i-drive.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*each* drive has its own concept of the current directory. `CD` changes the current directory, and if you specify a drive letter, it changes the current directory of that drive, rather than (by default) the current drive.

If you want to change the current directory of a different drive, and *switch* the current drive to that drive also, you use `/d`:

```
CD /d D:\
```

Comment: IMHO, one of the most annoying things about `cmd`.  But that's how it has worked since drive letters were introduced in DOS ~30 years ago.

Comment: Thanks you sir... it worked. It worked even without last "\" character.