# How to change current working directory using a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

This is essentially a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138507/how-to-change-current-working-directory-using-a-batch-file), with the difference that the answer given does not seem to work. I also want to use a batch script to change the directory, but the given answer does no work:

```
cd /C C:\Users
The specified path is invalid.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You send /C instead of /D ?

Comment: Oh, it looked to me `/D` denotes the drive letter. So with this option it works.

Answer (score 2):

cd /C c:/Users does not work for me either

But

```
cd /D c:\Users
```

...works fine, as described here: [How to change current working directory using a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138507/how-to-change-current-working-directory-using-a-batch-file)

Syntax:

```
CD [/D] [drive:][path]
CD [..]
```

Comment: Yes, it would be good to know that `/D` is an option and not some obscure 'thing'. You never can be sure if expressions are options like `/D` or `-d` or `--d` or wahtever, or some crazy windows batch exception.