# Running python script in python shell from a windows batch file

Tags: python, windows, batch-file

I'm trying to run a python script "index.py" in python shell from a .bat file on windows.
I tried this first script but it will only open my script in the Python UI without running it :

```
@echo off
set IDLEDIR=C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\idlelib\
set FILEDIR=D:\myfolder\
start "IDLE" "%IDLEDIR%..\..\pythonw.exe" "%IDLEDIR%idle.pyw" %FILEDIR%index.py
pause
```

I tried this second script, but I have issues with os.listdir(relativefolder/) in my python script, as if the relative folder was not calculated from the script location but from the .bat file location

```
@echo off
set FILEDIR=D:\myfolder\
python "%FILEDIR%index.py"
pause
```

Could you help me find out how to fix this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second approach is correct.

To solve the import problem you should fix your python code using a different approach:
In the following code `curdir` will have the name of the folder where your script is located, you can work upon this to do what you want.

```py
import sys
import os
curdir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

Or you could change the working directory using the batch script.
Check [How to change current working directory using a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138507/how-to-change-current-working-directory-using-a-batch-file/5138524#:%7E:text=Just%20use%20cd%20%2Fd%20%25root,directories%20to%20a%20network%20share.)
.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answer !

My end goal was to execute multiple scripts at the same time, so thanks to your answer, I changed my code to this :

```
@echo off
set FILEDIR=D:\myfolder\
for /d %%i in (%FILEDIR%*) do ( 
    CD /D "%%i"
    start /B python "index.py"
) 
pause
```

And it's working as expected.